# Multi Line button not showing all content correctly

Tags: xamarin.forms

I am using a list view  now  instead of adding to the stack but am having an issue am using synfusion  button to provide me a multiline button

```
<ListView x:Name="lvSessions" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Always">
    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <ViewCell>
                <StackLayout >
                    <syncfusion:SfButton Clicked="SfButton_Clicked"
                                        AutomationId="{Binding Id}" 
                     Text="{Binding Name}"  TextColor="White"  
                     VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand">

                        <syncfusion:SfButton.Content>
                            <StackLayout>
                                <Label Text="{Binding Name}" BackgroundColor="Black"
                                     TextColor="White"  HorizontalOptions="Center"> 
                                </Label>
                                <Label Text="{Binding StartDate}" 
                                    BackgroundColor="Black" TextColor="White" 
                                    HorizontalOptions="Center"></Label>
                                <BoxView Margin="10,10,10,10"></BoxView>
                            </StackLayout>
                                            
                        </syncfusion:SfButton.Content>

                    </syncfusion:SfButton>

                                   
                </StackLayout>
            </ViewCell>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListView.ItemTemplate>
</ListView>
```

But for some reason its chopping of some of my text as shown in the picture below colours are not what used in app its black and white but this would make it easier to show u what is wrong.

[image]

Thanks for advance

Comment: Have you tried adding "VerticalContentAlignment="Center" on the label?

Comment: Yeah same result

Comment: Try using a TextBlock which will give you plenty of nice options like text wrapping, I imagine your solution will be in there.

Comment: Am wanting a button so that it can be clickable like a button its used for the players check in screen so needs to be touch enabled

Comment: TextBlock is not a standard control @ol

Comment: I would set a WidthRequest large enough for the longest text. On each label and/or on StackLayout.

Comment: ListView supports both ItemTapped and ItemSelected events, so rows are inherently tappable without using a button.  I'd also suggest setting `UnevenRows=true` and/or setting a height value for the button

Comment: I went with a Text Cell in the end thanks for your suggestions I think  that may have been what @OllieSharratt had meant a TextCell and not a TextBlock

Answer (score 2):

As oli said above  I used a Text cell to achieve this.

```
 <ListView x:Name="lvSessions" ItemTapped="lvSessions_ItemTapped"
   HorizontalOptions="Center"  VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Always">
    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <TextCell x:Uid="{Binding SessionId}"   Text="{Binding 
           Name}" Detail="{Binding StartDate, StringFormat='{0:MMMM 
           dddd dd, yyyy}'}" DetailColor="White" TextColor="White" />
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListView.ItemTemplate>
</ListView>
```

As Jason also said U can use the ItemTapped event to hook into the orignal object as like below.

```
private async void lvSessions_ItemTapped(object sender, 
                                           ItemTappedEventArgs e)
{ 
     var session = e.Item as Session;
     if (session == null) return;
     int item = (int)session.Id;

     var playerCheckin = new PlayerCheckinPage(item);

     await Navigation.PushAsync(playerCheckin);
  }
```